# Deleted answers

Tags: support

A moderator with 35K reputation, deleted my answer, with no negative points, and no voting. I cannot undelete, and I do not know the reason. The answer was well worked. The only way I can see this is as censorship. Do you know if there is way to contact the moderator, or view the reason it was deleted?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What question was it an answer to? Do you think your answer was deleted because of something in its content?

Answer (score 0):

Me too. A cynic might think that certain ideas are off-limits. Lol. It would be helpful to to able to interrogate the decision.